# How can I get the results of a query in bigquery into a list?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm running a DAG that runs multiple stored procedures in Bigquery in each DAG run. Currently, my code is the following

```
sp_names = [
    'sp_airflow_test_1',
    'sp_airflow_test_2'
]

# Define DAG
with DAG(
    dag_id,
    default_args = default_args) as dag:
    
    for sp in sp_names:
        i = i + 1
        
        task_array.append(
            BigQueryOperator(
                task_id='run_{}'.format(sp),
                sql="""CALL `[project].[dataset].{}`();""".format(sp),
                use_legacy_sql=False
            )
        )
    
    if i != len(sp_names):
        task_array[i - 1] >> task_array[i]
```

I'd like my list "sp_names" to be the result of a query I do to a 1 column table that is stored on my BQ dataset, instead of being hardcoded like it is right now.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use the [BigQueryHook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.3.0/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py#L64) to execute such query. You can use the [BigQuery.get_records](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.3.0/airflow/providers/google/cloud/hooks/bigquery.py#L189) function to do that.

Comment: Thanks, Oluwafemi Sule, I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 1):

To execute multiple Bigquery with a similar SQL structure, create BigQueryOperator dynamically by create_dynamic_task function.

```
# funtion to create task
def create_dynamic_task(sp):
    task = BigQueryOperator(
        task_id='run_{}'.format(sp),
        sql="""CALL `[project].[dataset].{}`();""".format(sp),
        use_legacy_sql=False
    )
    return task


# dynamically create task
task_list = []
for sp in sp_names:
    task_list.append(create_dynamic_task(sp))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm going to try these changes, but I don't think that answers my main question though.

Comment: Just want to confirm, you want to get BigQueryOperator execution result?

BigQueryOperator executes BigQuery SQL queries in a specific BigQuery database, I didn't see any BigQueryOperator return value in source code: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.html#BigQueryOperator